# Forced To Use mapply Is There A Workaround

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with a single column "Terms". This could contain a string of multiple words. Each term contains at least two words or more, no upper limit.

From this column "Terms", I would like to extract the last word and store it in a new column "Last".

```
# load library
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)

# read csv 
df <- read("filename.txt",stringsAsFactors=F)

# show df
head(df)

#              Term
# 1 this is for the
# 2   thank you for
# 3   the following
# 4   the fact that
# 5       the first
```

I have prepared a function `LastWord` which works well when a single string is given.
However, when a vector of string is given, it still works with the first string in the vector. This has forced me to use `mapply` when used with `mutate`, to add a column as seen below.

```
LastWord <- function(InputWord) {
    stri_sub(InputWord,stri_locate_last(str=InputWord, fixed=" ")[1,1]+1, stri_length(InputWord))
}

df <- mutate(df, Last=mapply(LastWord, df$Term))
```

Using `mapply` makes the process very slow. I generally need to process around 10 to 15 million lines or terms at a time. It takes hours.

Could anyone suggest a way to create the `LastWord` function that works with vector rather than a string?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "vector of string is given"? Where is it given? If you have a data.frame, each column should have a vector of length 1. Also, can you make your example reproducible (use for example `dput()`)?

Comment: I think you're just looking for `df$LastWord <- stri_extract_last_words(df$Term)`

Comment: @Roman Lustrik - illustrated as "given" as below
vctTextLines <- c("this is a line one", "this is line two", "this is line three")
LastWord(vctTextLines)

Comment: @konvas - one more query; how can I get the whole line EXCEPT the last word

Comment: @CyrusLentin I've added an answer with more details

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try:

```
df$LastWord <- gsub(".* ([^ ]+)$", "\\1", df$Term)
df
             # Term  LastWord
# 1 this is for the       the
# 2   thank you for       for
# 3   the following following
# 4   the fact that      that
# 5       the first     first
```

In the `gsub` call, the expression between the brackets matches anything that is not a space at least one time (instead of `[^ ]+`, `[a-zA-Z]+` could work too) at the end of the string (`$`). The fact that it is in between brackets permit to capture the expression with `\\1`. So `gsub` only keeps what is in between brackets as replacement.

*EDIT*:
As @akrun mentionned in the comments, in this case, `sub` can also be used instead of `gsub`.

Comment: can you please explain `([^ ]+)` and `\\1` in `gsub`?

Comment: @Pgibas, I added an explanation, which I hope is clear. Don't hesitate to ask if it is not or if you need further explanation

Comment: @akrun, yes you're totally right. I almost never use `sub` although it is often enough. I'll edit to precise that. Thanks

Comment: @akrun - one more query; how can I get the whole line EXCEPT the last word ... any ideas

Comment: @CyrusLentin, `gsub("(.*) [^ ]+$", "\\1", df$Term)` should do it (or `gsub("(.* )[^ ]+$", "\\1", df$Term)` if you want to keep the space) ; and as before, `sub` can also be used...

Comment: @CathG - works; Thanks; Would appreciate a small explanation on the regex used.

Comment: @CyrusLentin, for the one in comments ? instead of capturing the last word, it captures (with the brackets) everything before it (except the space) and replace the strings by what was captured.

Answer (score 4):

To extract the last word only, you can use a vectorized function from `stringi` directly which should be very fast

```
library(stringi)
df$LastWord  <- stri_extract_last_words(df$Term)
```

Now if you want two new columns, one containing all words but the last and another one containing the last words, you can use some regular expression like

```
stri_match(df$Term, regex= "([\\w*\\s]*)\\s(\\w*)")
#      [,1]              [,2]          [,3]       
# [1,] "this is for the" "this is for" "the"      
# [2,] "thank you for"   "thank you"   "for"      
# [3,] "the following"   "the"         "following"
# [4,] "the fact that"   "the fact"    "that"     
# [5,] "the first"       "the"         "first"
```

So what you want is

```
df[c("ExceptLast", "LastWord")] <-
    stri_match(df$Term, regex= "([\\w*\\s]*)\\s(\\w*)")[, 2:3]
```

(Note that this won't work if `df$Term` contains only one word. In that case you will need to modify the regular expression, depending on which column you want it to be included in.)

Comment: Brilliant!!! This works & is fast!!! Thanks.

Would appreciate if you could also clarify how this works.
Specially how did you manage to create / fill two columns with single regex.

Also if I want just column 2 "ExceptLast" what regex should be used.

Comment: You can have a single regex return more than one matches. The way this works is that the parts of the regex that are included in parentheses are returned as columns. So if you don't need the last one you can simply get rid of the second pair of parentheses like `regex= "([\\w*\\s]*)\\s\\w*"` or remove the bit that's outside them altogether like `regex= "([\\w*\\s]*)"` (the latter will match all substrings consisting of "word" characters followed by  a space, so it doesn't match the last word since it is not followed by a space).